# Convert PyQt5 QPixmap to numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt, pyqt5, qpixmap

I have pixmap:

```
pixmap = self._screen.grabWindow(0,
                                 self._x, self._y,
                                 self._width, self._height)
```

I want to convert it to OpenCV format.
I tried to convert it to `numpy.ndarray` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552924/convert-qpixmap-to-numpy) but I got error `sip.voidptr object has an unknown size`

Is there any way to get numpy array (same format as `cv2.VideoCapture` `read` method returns)?

Comment: what is _screen?

Comment: QtWidgets.QApplication.primaryScreen()

Comment: Are you using the qt_image_to_array function?

Comment: yes. but without success. I don't sure it will work in my case at all

Comment: Have you verified that QPixmap is valid, have you tried to display or save it to a file?

Comment: yes, it's valid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got numpy array using this code:

```
channels_count = 4
pixmap = self._screen.grabWindow(0, self._x, self._y, self._width, self._height)
image = pixmap.toImage()
s = image.bits().asstring(self._width * self._height * channels_count)
arr = np.fromstring(s, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((self._height, self._width, channels_count))
```

Comment: That indeed worked for me, thanks, however, it raises a DeprecationWarning. It is therefore recommended to replace np.fromstring in your last code line with np.frombuffer.

Answer (score 6):

The copy can be avoided by doing:

```
channels_count = 4
pixmap = self._screen.grabWindow(0, self._x, self._y, self._width, self._height)
image = pixmap.toImage()
b = image.bits()
# sip.voidptr must know size to support python buffer interface
b.setsize(self._height * self._width * channels_count)
arr = np.frombuffer(b, np.uint8).reshape((self._height, self._width, channels_count))
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a function:

```
def QPixmapToArray(pixmap):
    ## Get the size of the current pixmap
    size = pixmap.size()
    h = size.width()
    w = size.height()

    ## Get the QImage Item and convert it to a byte string
    qimg = pixmap.toImage()
    byte_str = qimg.bits().tobytes()

    ## Using the np.frombuffer function to convert the byte string into an np array
    img = np.frombuffer(byte_str, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((w,h,4))

    return img
```

Comment: Consider add explanation about your solution, only code answer can be helpful for some, but not for everyone

Comment: Comments added to the answer.

Comment: this gives me `AttributeError: 'sip.voidptr' object has no attribute 'tobytes'`. did something change in the framework?

Comment: @MarkCh sip.voidptr indicates that its most likely that your QImg is empty.

Comment: @Ivan No it appears when it's non empty