# How to convert a QPixmap's image into a bytes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qimage, qpixmap

I want to take an image's data from a QLabel and then store it into a PostgreSQL Database, but I cannot store it as QPixmap, first I need to convert it into a bytes. That's what I want to know.

I've read part of the pyqt5's doc, specially the QImage and QPixmap's section but haven't seen what I am looking for.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ii_e_desu_ne.jpg"))
        self.setFixedSize(400,400)
        self.label.setFixedSize(200, 200)
        self.label.move(50, 50)
        self.show()

    #All is set now i want to convert the QPixmap instance's image 
    #into a byte string

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
ventana = Widget()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020672/convert-pyqt5-qpixmap-to-numpy-ndarray) for converting a `QPixmap` to a `numpy.ndarray` should work. Just omit the last step which converts the data from a byte string to the numpy array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to convert [`QPixmap`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) to bytes you must use [`QByteArray`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html) and [`QBuffer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuffer.html):

```
# get QPixmap from QLabel
pixmap = self.label.pixmap()

# convert QPixmap to bytes
ba = QtCore.QByteArray()
buff = QtCore.QBuffer(ba)
buff.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly) 
ok = pixmap.save(buff, "PNG")
assert ok
pixmap_bytes = ba.data()
print(type(pixmap_bytes))

# convert bytes to QPixmap
ba = QtCore.QByteArray(pixmap_bytes)
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
ok = pixmap.loadFromData(ba, "PNG")
assert ok
print(type(pixmap))

self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

The same is done with QImage, the "PNG" is the format to be converted since QImage/QPixmap abstracts the file format, you can use the formats indicated [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#reading-and-writing-image-files).